# error in an election program with while loop

Tags: java, loops

I wrote this program to calculate the total number of votes that each person got in an election, and to enter multiple districts.  When I try to enter another district the program just prints out the votes received from the first district instead of setting up another poll.  What is wrong with it and how do I fix it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Election{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int votesForPolly = 0;  // number of votes for Polly in each precinct
        int votesForErnest = 0; // number of votes for Ernest in each precinct
        int totalPolly = 0;     // running total of votes for Polly
        int totalErnest = 0;    // running total of votes for Ernest
        String response = "";    // answer (y or n) to the "more precincts" question

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println ();
        System.out.println ("Election Day Vote Counting Program");
        System.out.println ();
        // Initializations

        // Loop to "process" the votes in each precinct
        {
            System.out.println ("Enter Votes? Enter Y or N");
            response=scan.next().toUpperCase();
            if (response.equals("Y")){
                response="Yes"; 
                System.out.println ("Enter votes for Polly:");
                votesForPolly=scan.nextInt();
                totalPolly=totalPolly+ votesForPolly;
                System.out.println ("Enter votes for Ernest:");
                votesForErnest=scan.nextInt();
                totalErnest=totalErnest+ votesForErnest;
                System.out.println ("Enter another District? Enter Y or N");
                response=scan.next().toUpperCase(); 
            }else{

                int count = 0;

                while (count == 1){ 

                    // Print out the results

                }
            } 
            System.out.println ("Total votes for Polly is: " + totalPolly);
            System.out.println ("Total votes for Ernest is: " + totalErnest); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh god please fix the indentation.

Comment: also, please explain a bit. Just posting the entire code and asking people to find the bug for you is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current looping is broken (because you start with `count = 0`, therefore `while (count == 1)` is not entered, I would rewrite it as follows

```
final String msg = "Enter Votes for District %d?"
    + " Enter Y to continue, N to stop.\n";
// Loop to "process" the votes in each precinct
for (int i = 1;; i++) {
  System.out.printf(msg, i);
  response = scan.next().toUpperCase();
  if (response.startsWith("N")) {
    break;
  }
  System.out.println("Enter votes for Polly: ");
  votesForPolly = scan.nextInt();
  totalPolly += votesForPolly;
  System.out.println("Enter votes for Ernest: ");
  votesForErnest = scan.nextInt();
  totalErnest += votesForErnest;
}
System.out.printf("Total votes for Polly is: %d\n"
      + totalPolly);
System.out.printf("Total votes for Ernest is: %d\n"
      + totalErnest);
```

Comment: I changed this and it still did not enter the loop body.  What am I doing wrong and why isn't it entering the loop?

Answer (score 1):

You are not looping through the polling section.

Change

```
    if (response.equals("Y")){
```

to

```
    while (response.equals("Y")){
```

and remove the else statement.